# Keyboard not dismissing when another UITextField is tapped that brings up a picker

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I have 2 text fields that I am working with each one  when clicked opens up a picker wheel with a toolbar on top that gives the option to dismiss the picker and bring up a keyboard everything works fine unless you dismiss the picker and bring up the keyboard then click the next textfield. I get the keyboard on top with the new pickerview behind it. And the only way to get the keyboard to go away is to click back in the first textfield and click done or anywhere on the screen (not a textfield).

here is my code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i<[self.fieldsArray count]; i++) {
        if ([self.fieldsArray objectAtIndex:i] == textField) {
            UITextField *input = [self.fieldsArray objectAtIndex:i];

            if (input.tag == 3 && !self.overrideDriver) {
                [self animatePickDriverForInput:input];
            }
            if (input.tag == 4 && !self.overrideVehicle) {
                [self animatePickVehicleForInput:input];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here are some other methods used:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldFinished:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;

}

- (void)animatePickDriverForInput:(UITextField *)input
{
    if ([self.drivers count] > 0) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self showPickDriver];
    } else {
        //untested
        [input addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldFinished:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    }
}


- (void)animatePickVehicleForInput:(UITextField *)input
{
    if ([self.vehicles count] > 0) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self showPickVehicle];
    } else {
        //untested
        [input addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldFinished:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    }
}

- (void)allowManualEntryOfDriver
{
    [self.additionalButtonPickerHelper animateDismiss:self.pickDriver];
    self.overrideDriver = YES;
    [self.driver becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)allowManualEntryOfVehicle
{
    [self.additionalButtonPickerHelper animateDismiss:self.pickVehicle];
    self.overrideVehicle = YES;
    [self.vehicle becomeFirstResponder];
}



- (void)showPickVehicle {
    self.pickVehicle = [self.additionalButtonPickerHelper createPicker:self.pickVehicle WithTag:2 WithOtherButtonText:@"Add Other Vehicle"];
    [self.additionalButtonPickerHelper showPicker:self.pickVehicle WithDoneAction:@selector(dismissVehiclePicker) OrWithOtherAction:@selector(allowManualEntryOfVehicle)];
}

- (void)showPickDriver {
    self.pickDriver = [self.additionalButtonPickerHelper createPicker:self.pickDriver WithTag:1 WithOtherButtonText:@"Add Other Driver"];
    [self.additionalButtonPickerHelper showPicker:self.pickDriver WithDoneAction:@selector(dismissDriverPicker) OrWithOtherAction:@selector(allowManualEntryOfDriver)];
}
```

edit:

More code:

```
- (void)dismissDriverPicker
{
    [self.additionalButtonPickerHelper animateDismiss:self.pickDriver];
}

- (void)dismissVehiclePicker
{
    [self.additionalButtonPickerHelper animateDismiss:self.pickVehicle];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

This may not be the most efficient way to do this but im new to objective c and looking for a solution that I can understand. Thanks!

edit here is a picture [image: keyboard being stuck]

Comment: recheck delegates for each textfield

Comment: in your case no need to show the keyboard right?

Comment: when you are opening picker, just make [textField resignFirstResponder] to all your textfields..

Comment: What happend my dear frnd . Have you got your answer ?

Comment: @BluGeni : have you tried [textField resignFirstResponder] for both text fields before opening picker?

Comment: are you presenting this view controller as modalViewController in formsheet style ?? If so there it is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can try to use property of textField : **inputView**

> The custom input view to display when the text field becomes the first
>   responder.

So, you can show this view instead of keyboard, and don't handle it manually.

**Or:**

Wrong behavior for now occur, because keyboard for second textfield is shown also. So you need not only to resign first responder of first field, but also implement:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)field {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: how can i use input view in my case?

Comment: In viewDidLoad: create and configure your pickerView as before, and assign 'secondTextField.inputView = pickerView;' After will appear your pickerView instead of keyboard. So you don't need to handle it appear manually

Answer (score 0):

please try to use this one

```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [self showPickerView];
        return NO;
    }

    - (void)showPickerView
    {
       // ----- here create your picker view --------
    }
```

and you can use second one way but this is not proper way...so i say to prefer first one method.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: when i try the first method nothing happens now when i click the text field. The second method has no effect

Comment: i got the solution. these codes wont work if the view controller is presented as modalViewController with formsheet style..

Answer (score 0):

for getting like this you can use this one

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self showPickDriver];

    return NO;
}
```

or

otherwise better to use labels with tap Gestures then you can solve this problem easily.

Comment: @ BluGeni:use labels with gestures.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` includes the `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` properties to address this very situation:

> **`inputView`**
>
> If the value in this property is `nil`, the text field displays the standard system keyboard when it becomes first responder. Assigning a custom view to this property causes that view to be presented instead.

Comment: how can i implement this for my case?

Comment: Assign your `UIPickerView`s to the `inputView` property of the `UITextField`s they correspond to (which I think are `self.driver` and `self.vehicle`), and then let the OS show and hide them just like a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

if the view controller containing the textfield is presented as **modalViewController** with **formsheet style**, then you have to override the below given method to make it work properly.

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal 
{
   return NO;
}
```